# Numerical personal code validator

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript function and I have to create a prompt where I need to input a number and based on that to run the function above.

The JavaScript part is correct but I don't know how to create the front interface and link it to the function.

I am only allowed to use JavaScript and HTML. (homework)

```
function validCNP( p_cnp ) {
    var i=0 , year=0 , hashResult=0 , cnp=[] , hashTable=[2,7,9,1,4,6,3,5,8,2,7,9];
    if( p_cnp.length !== 13 ) { return false; }
    for( i=0 ; i<13 ; i++ ) {
        cnp[i] = parseInt( p_cnp.charAt(i) , 10 );
        if( isNaN( cnp[i] ) ) { return false; }
        if( i < 12 ) { hashResult = hashResult + ( cnp[i] * hashTable[i] ); }
    }
    hashResult = hashResult % 11;
    if( hashResult === 10 ) { hashResult = 1; }
    year = (cnp[1]*10)+cnp[2];
    switch( cnp[0] ) {
        case 1  : case 2 : { year += 1900; } break;
        case 3  : case 4 : { year += 1800; } break;
        case 5  : case 6 : { year += 2000; } break;
        case 7  : case 8 : case 9 : { year += 2000; if( year > ( parseInt( new Date().getYear() , 10 ) - 14 ) ) { year -= 100; } } break;
        default : { return false; }
    }
    if( year < 1800 || year > 2099 ) { return false; }
    return ( cnp[12] === hashResult );
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems that you don't need a real interface but just a way to input a number, the most simple case is to use the javascript method window.prompt()... then pass the value to your function

```
var data = prompt('Type a number');
console.log(validCNP(data));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: Can you please explain better. I am really new to coding. I need to have a page with a button or a prompt that shows on load where to input my number and then to get an alert (true or false) or a message on page based on that function.